# How to find the least in $E^{\circ}=\frac{5S^g}{162}+\frac{C^\circ}{50}+\frac{2\pi^2}{360}\textrm{rad}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The problem is as follows:

Let $S^{\circ}$, $C^{g}$ and $R\,\textrm{rad}$ the measures of a positive angle in sexagesimal, centesimal and radian degrees respectively such as:

$$E^{\circ}=\frac{5S^g}{162}+\frac{C^\circ}{50}+\frac{2\pi^2}{360R}\textrm{rad}$$

Using this information find the least $E$.

The alternatives in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{6}\\
2.&\textrm{8}\\
3.&\textrm{10}\\
4.&\textrm{12}\\
\end{array}$

How exactly should I find the least angle here?.

So far what I remember is that the proportions between each unit are the same in the sense of:

$\frac{S}{360}=\frac{C}{400}=\frac{R}{2\pi}$

Using this information you may find a relationship between the variables.

Plugin these in the above equation I'm getting:

However I find confusing **why** the degree symbols for $S$ and $C$ appears swapped then I figured that what it might be intended could be that the digits for the angle are represented by the letter but the degree is contrary to what its unit mentions.

For $\frac{5S^g}{162}$:

$\frac{5S^g}{162}\times\frac{360^\circ}{400^g}=\frac{1S}{36}^{\circ}$

For $\frac{C^\circ}{50}$:

Since;

$\frac{S}{360}=\frac{C}{400}$

$C=\frac{10}{9}S$

$\frac{C^\circ}{50}=\frac{10S^\circ}{9}\times \frac{1}{50}=\frac{1S^\circ}{45}$

For: $\frac{2\pi^2}{360R}\textrm{rad}$

Since this case $R$ matches with the degree symbol $\textrm{rad}$ then I would apply the equation:

$\frac{S^{\circ}}{180}=\frac{R\rad}{\pi}$

$R \textrm{rad}=\frac{S^\circ \pi}{180}$

$\frac{2\pi^2}{360R}\textrm{rad}=\frac{2\pi^2 \times 180}{360S^\circ \pi}=\frac{\pi}{S^\circ}$

Then:

$E^{\circ}=\frac{5S^g}{162}+\frac{C^\circ}{50}+\frac{2\pi^2}{360R}\textrm{rad}$

$E^{\circ}=\frac{1S}{36}^{\circ}+\frac{1S^\circ}{45}+\frac{\pi}{S^\circ}$

$E^{\circ}=\frac{S^2+20\pi}{20S}$

Then I assume that this latter expression must me minimized but would it be used calculus for this?

If so:

$E^{\circ}\,'=\frac{1}{20}-\frac{\pi}{S^2}$

Equating this to zero:

$E^{\circ}=2\sqrt{5\pi}$

But I don't know if this is what it was intended?.

Can someone help me here?. I'm stuck, why it doesn't matches any of the alternatives given or could it be that I made a mistake?. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that $R$ rad $=\dfrac {S^\circ \pi}{180^\circ} $, it is not true that $\dfrac {2\pi^2}{360R}$rad $= \dfrac {2\pi^2 \times 180^\circ}{360S^\circ\pi}$; the latter is actually equal to $\dfrac {2\pi^2}{360R \text{ rad}}$. To resolve this, we consider the numerical value of $R$ and the conversion of rad to degrees (sexagesimal) seperately:

$$R = \frac {S \pi}{180}, \quad 1 \text{ rad }=\frac {180}{\pi}^\circ$$

Now we have:

$$\frac {2\pi^2}{360R} \text{ rad } = \frac {2\pi^2 \times 180}{360S\pi} \times \frac {180^\circ}{\pi}=\frac {180^\circ}{S}$$

$$E^\circ = \frac{5S^g}{162}+\frac{C^\circ}{50}+\frac{2\pi^2}{360R}\textrm{rad} = \frac {S^\circ}{36} + \frac {S^\circ}{45} + \frac {180^\circ }S = \left(\frac S{20}+\frac{180}S\right)^\circ$$

To minimize this we may use calculus, or better yet, the 2-term form of AM $\ge$ GM:

$$a+b\ge 2\sqrt{ab}$$

$$\frac S{20}+\frac{180}S\ge2\sqrt{\frac S{20}\times \frac {180}S} =6$$

Hence the minimum of $E^\circ$ is $6^\circ$ (which occurs at $S = 60$).

Comment: Wait! what's the meaning of the 2-way form of $AM\geq GM$? I don't know **from where did you got to** $a+b\geq 2\sqrt ab$ the latter part is confusing can you explain this better?.It seems that the latter expression requires more algebra. Where did you got that $S=60^{\circ}$?. This part is where I'm stuck.

Comment: AM $\ge$ GM states that $\dfrac {a+b}2 \ge \sqrt{ab}$. The two-term case can be proven by observing $(\sqrt a - \sqrt b)^2 \ge 0 \leadsto a-2\sqrt{ab}+ b \ge 0$. Equality occurs iff $a=b$, and $\dfrac S{20} = \dfrac {180}S \implies S = \sqrt{20 \times 180} = 60$.

Comment: I think the source of confusion here was the **meaning** of $AM$ and $GM$ what are these? Line segments? angles? what?. **Why** did you used $a=b$? **why an equality would render this expression the least** can you explain this part?.By the way I assume that maybe **AM = arithmetic mean** is greater and equal of the **geometric mean**? is this what you meant? Again, if this is the case I don't know why **would it be used here to find the least value?** Please explain I'm stuck there.

Comment: Sorry I think I got it, I believe you mention this because the least value is zero hence you can find the least by equating both. Am I right with this part?.

Comment: For the inequality of arithmetic and geometric means, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means. Using the inequality we have $\dfrac S{20} + \dfrac {180}S \ge 6$, which is attained at $S=60$; this shows that $6^\circ $ is indeed the minimum.